# how to use php function within style tag

Tags: php, html, css, function, background

I want to add background image dynamically in style tag and return to div using php code. So I use my general logic. but It doesn't work. I write code as following

**CSS**

```
<style>
.topadd{
background-image: url('../add/<?php echo $add?>');
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $query="SELECT img FROM addbar where position='logo'";
    $result=$con->query($query) or die($con->error);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $add=$row['img'];       
        if($add!=""){
            echo "<div class='topadd'></div>";
        }   
    }
?>
```

I know there is no connection between style tag which is included in head and php code. I can't use php function within css that returns variable as html. Or any idea to fix this problem ?

Comment: are u using both in same file ?

Comment: Yeah ! both are in same file

Comment: `echo "<div class='topadd' style='background-image:".$add."'></div>";`

Comment: Thanks for response, I want to use external or internal css than inline css. because there are lot of images. Is it any idea to link with internal css ?

Comment: @DipakOjha not possible with external css, if you want to use internal css than you have to `create different classes for different divs`, as they all will have different images, so a single class for a single div... so it will be same like inline css...

Answer (score 0):

You can modified this with
    CSS

```
<style>
.topadd{

width:100%;
height:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$query="SELECT img FROM addbar where position='logo'";
$result=$con->query($query) or die($con->error);
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $add=$row['img'];       
    if($add!=""){
          echo "<div class='topadd' style='background-image: url(../add/'".$add.")'></div>";
    }   
}
?>
```

i hope it may help you